# react router 4 and express : cannot GET

Tags: reactjs, express, react-router

I'm trying to use react router 4, with an Express server.

If I set the path to "/", it works.
But if I set the path "/test", and visit test, I get "Cannot GET /test".
Is it because React Router 4 is incompatible with Express ?

app-client.js:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Board from './components/Board';

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <Route path="/test" component={Board} />
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
    , document.getElementById('react-container'));
```

Board.js:

```
var React = require('react');
var createReactClass = require('create-react-class');

var Board = createReactClass({
    render(){
        return (<h1>Board</h1>)
    }    
});

export default Board;
```

Comment: What do you mean `But if I set the path "/test"`? If you mean navigate there through the browser (like enter it in the URL bar and press ENTER button), as opposed to navigating there in React, then those are 2 different things. It's server side vs client side routing

Comment: I want the component to show up when I navigate to /test in the browser

Comment: Then see Amr's answer for handling that server side. Also please search for your issue before posting, a quick Google search would have given you the answer from countless sources.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To make sure all your routes are handled by React after defining all you express routes we will make sure any route that is not handled in express app will be redirected to the `index.html` in the react app to be handeled like so:

```
// All expressjs routes
// then
app.get('*', (req, res) => {                       
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'the path to your react project', 'index.html'));                               
});
```

Comment: Many thanks Amr. I since reverted back to an older react router version. But I'm pretty sure this would have solved the problem so I choose this as my answer.  I'll appreciate if someone could explain why `app.get('*', `... is not needed for older react/express setup. I've heard about "react router v4" being "dynamic", but I'm not sure what this means (components rendered on the fly ?).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue as OP and followed Amr Aly's directions AS WELL as checking out a couple blog posts and github issues, like the following: https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-cannot-get-url-refresh/

However, after following their directions, this error would get thrown:

> “Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <”

You then go on a wild goose chase, as seen here in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37904990/how-to-fix-babel-react-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token).

To resolve OP's issue AND not deal with the uncaught syntax error, try the following:

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, '../public');
  app.use(express.static(publicPath));
  app.use('*', express.static(publicPath));
}
```